# Worklight 6.2 => Xcode => buildtime.sh => error

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

After I deploy my worklight project to Xcode and try to run it, I get the following error from some worklight-specific build script called "buildtime.sh". (I've googled, this is *not* a permission denied problem - it's different.

The project was produced following the tutorial instructions from: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620

1. I created the hybrid project
2. Deployed the project to Xcode using: "Run As" => Xcode project
3. Then tried to build and run the project

I'm using Worklight 6.2. Here is a screenshot of the error in Xcode:

What does "Set: Entry, ':buildtime', Does Not Exist" mean and how can I fix it?

[image: buildtime.sh error from Worklight-deployed Xcode project]

Comment: Please mention fuller reproduction steps.

Comment: OK, updated. What other information can I provide?

Comment: What is a "native" project adapter? I have never heard of this in terminology in Worklight. Are you referring to NativeAPI application type?

Comment: Sorry, yes, a native API. The point is that I deployed the project natively to Xcode already and am now operating within Xcode trying to get it to run.

Comment: There is zero relation between a Hybrid application with the iPhone environment and a NativeAPI application. The NativeAPI is a set of resources that you are supposed to copy over into a **fully native application you create in Xcode** (not the Hybrid app you created via Worklight Studio). It contains required Worklight SDK and connectivity files. Do you understand the difference? Why do you create both?

Comment: Sorry again - please just ignore the Native words - that's not the point of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting out the "echo" line in the offending script solved the defect in Worklight.

Hopefull setting a timestamp for building is not essential to a functioning Worklight.

Answer (score -2):

Your question mixes two distinct Worklight application types that are not mixable.
The steps described in the question are not possible to recreate as well.

In a Worklight project that the iOS NativeAPI application type was added to, there is no Run As > Xcode project option. This option is available *only* if adding a *Hybrid* application type to the project and the iPhone or iPad *environment* to it. Only then it is possible to right-click on the environment folder and select Run As > Xcode project.

I have created a new Worklight Worklight and:

- Added a Hybrid application
- Added the iPhone environment
- Right-clicked on the "iphone" folder and selected Run As > Xcode project

The project was then built, deployed and opened in Xcode and finally launched in the iOS Simulator (end-to-end scenario). I cannot recreate your scenario.

Additionaly, in Xcode (as well as in the iphone\native folder in Worklight Studio) I can see the buildtime.sh file in the project resources:

In Xcode, the file is supposed to be inside the Other Resources folder.
In Eclipse, the file is supposed to be inside iphone\native folder.

If you do not see this file - that's strange. Try to first Run As > Run on Worklight Development server and verify the file exists in the native folder, although this should not be needed at all.

This is the contents of the buildtime.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
# 5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
# US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
# disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.

# Update buildtime in project
echo -n ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/worklight.plist | xargs -0 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :buildtime `date +\"%s\"`"
```

Either greatly expand on the existing reproduction steps or export your Worklight project for debugging (right-click on the Worklight project and select Export...; also make sure that this includes the .project file in the Export window).

Comment: The "native" terminology is irrelevant. I have clicked "Run As" => Xcode project by selecting the iphone icon in the Worklight native folder of the project and it fails in Xcode. Can we please focus on the Xcode problem? Thanks.

Comment: I've performed all of the steps successfully already (or I wouldn't have an Xcode project to begin with). I've added the hybrid application. Added the iphone environment and already stated that I've selected "Run As" => Xcode project. All of these things work fine.

But, when I click "Play" I get the "buildtime.sh" error above. Is there something not clear about that?

Comment: The file exists, if you would please re-read the question and the posted screenshot. The error does not result from the file's non-existence, it results form an error inside the script itself.